# Image validation issue in october CMS

Tags: octobercms

I have tried below code in my model file But its not working for me.

```
public $rules = [
        'desktop_img' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png',
        'mobile_img' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png'
    ];

public $customMessages = [
    'desktop_img.required' => 'Please Upload Large Image',
    'desktop_img.mimes' => 'Please Upload Valid Image',
    'mobile_img.required' => 'Please Upload Small Image',
    'mobile_img.mimes' => 'Please Upload Valid Image'
];
```

https://octobercms.com/docs/services/validation#rule-image

[image]

I have applied the validations for image types but still it thorough this error

I have also reviewed above link and tried for that but it isn't working for me.

Can anyone has the solution for it ? Please share your knowledge with me.  Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution on this ? i have a same problem which i raised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926676/octobercms-imagefile-validation-not-working-properly

Comment: @Hardik Patel , issue resolved or not?

Comment: Please follow the URL :https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2535
<br>

https://octobercms.com/forum/post/octobercms-imagefile-validation-not-working-properly