# OctoberCMS image(file) validation not working properly

Tags: octobercms

I am trying to put image(file) validations in my model file but it seems to be not working as I want.Here below is my scenario.

**fields.yaml**

```
fields:
    slider_image:
        label: 'Slider Image (jpg,png,gif) (1920 X 600)'
        mode: image
        fileTypes: 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif'
        useCaption: true
        thumbOptions:
            mode: crop
            extension: auto
        span: auto
        required: 1
        type: fileupload
```

**Model.php**

```
public $rules = [    
'slider_image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
];

public $customMessages = [                
            'slider_image.required' => 'Please select slider image',                
            'slider_image.mimes' => 'Please select valid slider image',                
];
```

As you can clearly see here I have a file upload option called as **slider_image** and in my **.yaml** file I have put validations to upload only **jpeg,jpg,png,gif**

But the issue is with my validation rules.

Even if I upload any other extension file (i.e. **.zip**) I m always having an error message saying

> Please select slider image

but it should rather display below error as I have already invalid extension file.

> Please select valid slider image

If I do not upload any image then it should display first error and if I upload an invalid image then it should display second error.

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my current scenario here ?

Additionally, I wanted to know if there is any validation rule available through which we can check height width of the image and set rule of minimum height width to upload and put validation message based on it in our model file.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, I have also asked this on [October GIT repo](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2535) and [October Support Forum](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/octobercms-imagefile-validation-not-working-properly) and waiting for help.

Comment: I think it's a problem of "concept" because the file was never uploaded to the server if does not match the filetypes so for this reason you can't trigger the mime validation but i think you can override the afterValidate() method and do your custom validation by your self an throw an `throw new ValidationException($validation);`

Comment: I see. But i do not know how to go through with this using afterValidate(). If you can guide me or provide me chunk of code as I am totally out of it implementing this part to be honest :(

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** levels of validation at play here. One is the built-in validation functionality of the file upload widget - that is what is configured in your fields.yaml in the widget options, i.e.

```
    mode: image
    fileTypes: 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif'
```

*and that is happening on the client side*. The fileuplod widget will then already point out to you (*on the client side*) that this type is not allowed if you upload for example a zip file, because: 1. You have specified `mode: image`. 2. You have specified `filetypes: jpeg,jpg,png,gif`. Your file upload will be simply not accepted *on the client side*, and so when submitting the form the file input will just be empty.

And so your *second* level of validation (specified by your $rules in **Model.php**), which is taking place after the form is submitted *on the server side* will then get an **empty** file input (because the upload widget has not even forwarded the type of file that you tried to uploaded), and will therefore answer with 'Please select slider image'.

So the validator is working correctly. Everything is working correctly. But if you want the mime validation in your **Model.php** to respond to unwanted file types you would have to remove the

```
fileTypes: 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif'
```

from your **fields.yaml**, because otherwise they won't even get through to your model validation.

To your second question: No, there is no such inbuilt validation for proper height and width of an image. But you can specify "imageHeight" and "imageWidth" in your fields.yaml to resize the uploaded image automatically.